# Rails 3 multi-level join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have been reading to understand the best Rails 3 way to do the following. I'd be very grateful for suggested approaches. (scopes?)

I have the following models:

```
class DonorCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :donors
end

class Donor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :donations
  belongs_to :donor_category
end

class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :donor
end
```

what I need is this:
"All donations associated with a given donor category, for given dates"
The date criteria is applied to Donation, but the donor category criterion is applied to Donor
So it is as if I need to filter the Donors which are applied to the Donation query.

Comment: Somehow a very good response was lost, with this formatting edit. I am still getting an error. the added relationship isn't working quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a helpful query method to Donor. And adding a `has_many ... through` on DonationCategory would give you easy access to the Donations from a given category, automatically joining the tables, like this:

```
class DonationCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :donors
    has_many :donations, through: :donors
end

class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.within_dates(start_date, end_date)
    where "created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", start_date, end_date
  end

end

# Query looks like this:
some_category.donations.within_dates(start_date, end_date)

# Or this:
DonorCategory.find(123).donations.within_dates(start_date, end_date)
```

To use the `through` option on `has_many`, you don't need to modify your database at all. Rails will get the `donations` from the donor_category's `donors`, by joining your donations, donors, and donor_categories tables.

You mentioned scopes. The `within_dates` class method is effectively a scope. `scope` is just [special rails syntax](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) for creating a class method that queries the database. It's a redundant mechanism, but [DHH likes it](https://twitter.com/#!/dhh/statuses/189874148259012608). And I agree that often a scope is easier on the eyes than the equivalent class method, but when the scope requires arguments, as it would here, I think the class method is actually more straightforward.

**UPDATE**

RFC1337's answer makes me realize the query method could be simplified:

```
def self.within_dates(start_date, end_date)
  where created_at: start_date..end_date
end
```

Comment: Rob, thanks so much. I tried your suggestion:class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :donor
  has_one :donor_category, through: :donor
  has_many :donation_items, :dependent => :destroy
  def self.for_category(id)
    where donor_category_id: id
  end
end
~                                      I get an error "Unknown column: donations.donor_category_id". Somehow it seems I have not defined the class method quite right.

Comment: Sorry, I made a tweak. See above.

Comment: Rob, thanks very much! Your tweaked approach works perfectly, and it taught me a lot too. Thanks also to "RFC1337" for the one-line answer. I used Rob's approach, but I'm going to incorporate the other approach into the application in other places. Thanks very much to both of you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like this:

```ruby
Donor.where(:donor_category => DonorCategory.find(id)).where(:date => start_date..end_date)
```

Comment: I like the date range in your `where`. I didn't know it allowed that. Neat.

Comment: `DonorCategory.find(id)` will do an extra query. Better change that to: `:donor_category_id => id`. This query returns donors, but the question states that donations should be returned, so you have to add `.first.donations` at the end.

Comment: @Mischa - Yeah, I know it would cause an extra query, resulting in a N+1 scenario. In this case, you could add a call to includes(:donor_category)  in order to prevent the N+1. In that case, only 2 queries would occur.